# convert string of C# dateTime to date of TypeScript

Tags: c#, angular

I kept dateTime in C# in the form of string

```
string result =DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

The result is: 20201110011515

In ts:

```
 date:string = 20201110011515
```

I want to convert it to Date of ts.

new Date(Tue Nov 10 2020 01:15:15 GMT+0200)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is there a reason for using `"yyyyMMddHHmmss"` over `"o"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually dates would get serialized to something like ISO 8601 (or use [`ToString("o")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier) as John suggests) that will already work with `new Date(dateStr)`. But if you are stuck with this specific format you can take the substring for each part:

```js
let dateStr = "20201110011515";
let year = dateStr.substring(0, 4);
let month = dateStr.substring(4, 6);
let day = dateStr.substring(6, 8);
let hour = dateStr.substring(8, 10);
let minute = dateStr.substring(10, 12);
let second = dateStr.substring(12, 14);

return new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
```